# How to sort a list of lists with IP subnets

Tags: python-2.7, networking

I have a list of lists of IPs as follows:

IPS = [["103.2.2.0/24", "23.33.3.0/25"], ["77.6.6.128/25", "33.45.3.0/25"]]

I would need to sort this based on the first item of every list inside the main list, so to have:

IPS_SORTED = [["77.6.6.128/25", "33.45.3.0/25"],["103.2.2.0/24", "23.33.3.0/25"]]

So from the "lowest" IP subnet to the highest.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested:

I used the netaddr python module to transform my ips into ip objects. After that I just did the following:

```
SortedIps = sorted(IP_List, key=lambda x:x[0].value
```

This sorts according to the first ip subnet in every sub-list.